# How can I sort words in corpus based on multiple tags? Python, nltk

Tags: python, tags, nltk

I wish to sort the list of words and their tags, from the one which has the biggest number of tags to the lowest one.

So far I have this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tagged = defaultdict(set)
for w in brown:
    tagged[w[0]].add(w[1])

for word in tagged:
    if len(tagged[word])>1:
        print (word, tagged[word])
```

It prints a list of all words which have more than 1 tag. How to sort it so the order is descending?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
items = sorted(tagged.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]), reverse=True)
for word, tags in items:
    if len(tags) <= 1:
        break
    print(word, tags)
```

It will sort all entries by the length of the value, in descending order.
The loop stops before the length-1 entries start being printed.

Comment: Thank you for help @lenz :)